# Software license for paid open-source app on Microsoft Store

Tags: licensing, open-source, software-distribution

What is the right software license to use in order to be able to sell my application, have it be open-source, and still be able to accept pull requests?

I am developing a productivity/utility application for Windows. I would like to release that application on the Microsoft Store as a paid application, with a free trial option, and also have the binaries available on GitHub.

The intention here is to allow users who have tried the app and liked it to pay for it and in turn get updates through the Store.

What worries me is that once I start getting pull requests, by accepting them I will find myself in sort of a grey area, since I will no longer be able to take advantage of the fact that I am the sole copyright owner, which is what allows me to distribute it (if my understanding is correct).

<del>I would also like to prevent other parties from redistributing my application.</del> Sorry, I meant preventing other parties from distributing it *for profit*.

Is there a standard license that fits these requirements? Should I just disable pull requests? Maybe just forget about open sourcing it and keep the source closed.

Comment: I'd suggest not calling the work 'open source' if you prevent other parties from redistributing your application. That would fall outside of the OSI's Open Source Definition. It would also fall outside of the FSF's free software definition.

Comment: Sorry, see the last edit.

Comment: alternately provide a killer plugin API. That way other peoples code is not what is being licenced, your app is, and these are third party extensions that you are not liable for, that you don't have to pr control, and if you want to can provide official extensions using.

Comment: @Kain0_0 That is an interesting idea. Inversely, I might also consider open-sourcing the core of the application and then moving functionality into a proprietary layer on top of that core API.

Comment: @paladin324 Banning others distributing for profit would still be outside the open source and free software definitions. And it may also be hard to define exactly - does it mean it can't be distributed on discs carried by a for-profit company like UPS? Or on network infrastructure run for profit?

Comment: @bdsl I wasn't aware of the legal ambiguity related to the term. I now see that my understanding of open-source licenses is flawed. I will reconsider my strategy and might implement something along the lines of what Kain0_0 has suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look into the description of the tags you used, I guess you overlooked the recommendation given there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think as far as the software license is concerned, you can choose any that you want, but of course it shouldn‘t be one that allows redistribution.
You may not even have to license the source code at all. In that case no one would be allowed to use it. You must license the executable, otherwise people would not be allowed to use it either.

If you accept a pull request, you are right, you are no longer the sole copyright holder, and you cannot sell the resulting binary any longer. In this case you need a collaborater agreement, this would stipulate that whoever submits the contribution sign their copyright over to you. I just don‘t think that ever anyone would do so without an incentive.

I think allowing pull requests is not a problem, but accepting them is.

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer, the above is my personal opinion and not legal advice.

Comment: That confirms my worries and points out some of the flaws in my strategy. I will reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know the precise play store rules, but on apple’s App Store you can’t have a paid GPL licensed app: Apples App Store rules say that customers pay *for the license*, not for the app. The GPL says that you can charge for the app, but you can’t charge for the license. Add these two together, and you can’t charge for a GPL licensed app on the App Store.